# Change URL in factory with input value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I want change my url parameter, starting search from a input.

I need change like for example:

```
return $http({
    url:'http://my-api.com/api/teste.php?' + 'input-value',
    method:'GET'
})
```

and this update after I change again my input!

currently I have in my code this:

```
.factory('netflixService', netflixService);

function netflixService($http, $log) {

   var API = 'http://netflixroulette.net/api/api.php?';
   $log.debug(API);

  return {
    getApi: function() {
        return $http({
            url:API,
            method:'GET'
        })
    }
  };
}
```

And I caught in this part :(

thks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getApi` method, take an argument. For example:

```
return {
    getApi: function(inputValue) {
        return $http({
            url:API + inputValue,
            method:'GET'
        })
    }
  };
```

Then you can call it in a controller like:

`netflixService.getApi('foobar');`